# I get this error : not-null property references a null or transient value : model.Agent.direction

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

In my `**JAVA SPRING BOOT**` application, I have two entities **AGENT** and **DIRECTION** and when I try to register an AGENT that is assigned to a direction I get this error: `**not-null property references a null or transient value : com.malla.assurancelafia.model.Agent.direction**`

The Agent entity:

```
public class Agent {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id_agent;
    private String nom_agent;
    private String prenom_agent;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_fonction", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Fonction fonction;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String login;
    private String password;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Etat etat = Etat.ACTIF;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_direction", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Direction direction;
}
```

The Direction entity :

```
public class Direction {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id_direction;
    private String libelle_direction;
    private String description_direction;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "direction", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Responsable responsable;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "direction", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Agent> agents;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Etat etat = Etat.ACTIF;
}
```

THe controller :

```
@PostMapping("saveAgent")
    public Agent saveA(@RequestBody Agent a) {
        return agentServiceImplement.saveAgent(a);
    }
```